# How can I change BrowserWindow hash url without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm loading a page in ElectronJS with `BrowserWindow.loadURL("http://google.com")`. Later on in my application, I need to update the the url by some hash values like `http://google.com/#start` and I want it to be done without reloading the page as it's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `location.assign('#start');` works for me inside a local URL.

You may want to try something like this (untested) from the main process:

```
let window = new BrowserWindow(/*...*/);
window.loadURL("http://google.com");
//
window.webContents.executeJavaScript("location.assign('#start');");
```

References:

- [contents.executeJavaScript()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback)
- [Location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)